# When I pair my Bluetooth headphones my WiFi drops out

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, bluetooth, headphones

Patient is Macbook Pro 2019 16/256 1.4 (Big Sur 11.3)

Problem:

When I pair my mouses (mx master 2s/mx master 3) my internet drops off at least 50% no matter its 2.4GHz or 5.0GHz. If I pair Bluetooth headphones too (edifier x3) my internet drops to 1Mb maybe or cuts off completely.

1. I went to an online support service and they told me to reset nvram etc but still doesn't work.
2. I found solution to rename the file bluetooth.plist and it was working for few hours.
3. I went again to service and they replaced the motherboard with a new one.
4. I found another solution just for few hours (`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.airport.bt.plist bluetoothCoexMgmt Hybrid`), and still nothing.

What can I do right now?  I'm just sad, because I was saving a lot of money for my first Mac but my old laptop for 200$ doesn't have problem no matter what I pair on Bluetooth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do my Macbook Pro's WiFi speeds drop significantly when paired with Bluetooth devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184788/why-do-my-macbook-pros-wifi-speeds-drop-significantly-when-paired-with-bluetoot)

Comment: Nope ;/, I tried it, thats what i wrote in number 2/3